# $http: how to get filename of headers from WebApi with CORS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I get issue that I can't get filename from headers of $http response

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Content-Length: 121257
>   Content-Type: application/pdf
>   Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
>   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Order-414.pdf
>   Date: Wed, 11 Feb 2015 05:32:25 GMT

I just want to get filename (Order-414.pdf) as pdf name when downloading. but in this code block:

```
   $http.get(httpPath, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
            .success(function (data, status, headers) {
                debugger;
                // just return content-type
                var header = headers();
```

header object just contains content-type.

```
Object {content-type: "application/pdf"}
```

I read somewhere that we need config CORS for WebAPI as:

```
  private static void RegisterCorsConfig(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "*");
        //var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion");
        //cors.ExposedHeaders.Add("*");
        //cors.ExposedHeaders.Add("filename");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
```

But it still doesn't work. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you need to add `Content-Disposition` instead of `filename` into `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

```
cors.ExposedHeaders.Add("Content-Disposition");
```

Answer (score 1):

Web API: I found that adding the following line code into the ExecuteAsync(...) method of my IHttpActionResult implementation worked (*'response'* is the HttpResponseMessage to be returned):

```
response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
```

Comment: This is great.  I was going absolutely nuts trying to get response headers.